# Scala shell not running without super user privilege on ubuntu

Tags: linux, scala, path, environment-variables, superuser

I have installed Scala via apt but when I try to run the Scala shell, it throws me a NoClassDefFoundError. When I try to run it using superuser privileges,it runs fine.
Scalac runs fine without superuser privileges.
after running the `env` command, I saw that `SCALA_HOME` was there but `PATH` for scala was not listed. I tried adding the path through `bashrc`, `profile` and `/etc/environment` but it isn't getting added to the `PATH`.
My `SCALA_HOME` is `/usr/share/scala`
My question is:
**How do I execute the Scala shell without superusr privileges?**

EDIT1: After tweaking with `SCALA_HOME` and `PATH` I no longer have `SCALA_HOME` in my environment

Answer (score 1):

On my ubuntu system (actually [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)) I have the following.

The primary executable in `/usr/bin` should already be in your `$PATH`. This is a sym-link to the actual executable.

```
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Apr 13 01:24 /usr/bin/scala -> /usr/share/scala/bin/scala
```

The real `scala` executable is a `bash` script.

```
8 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6208 Apr 13 01:24 /usr/share/scala/bin/scala
```

Note the file permissions on each.

I don't have `SCALA_HOME` set in my environment because the `scala` bash script does it's own calculations to figure that out.

Comment: I'm using mint. And my objective is to run the scala shell with just "scala" command from the terminal. How do I achieve it?

Comment: I've shown you how I achieve it. If your setup (links, files, permissions) looks like mine then the problem is elsewhere. If that's the case then it's likely that we don't have enough information to help you solve it.

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Aug 26 20:58 scala -> /etc/alternatives/scala`
This is the one in /usr/bin
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Aug 26 20:58 scala -> /usr/share/scala-2.11/bin/scala`
This is the one in /etc/alternatives
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5783 Dec 22 2015 scala`
This is the original exe

Comment: Execute this command from your home directory: `/etc/alternatives/scala` If you get the REPL then the problem _might_ be one of the sym links. If it fails then the error message is the first clue to tracking down the problem.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError
But no problem with sudo
Back to square one

Comment: I also changed the sym-links for the usr/bin/scala to usr/share/scala/bin/scala (which was previously ../share/scala-2.11/..) but still same result
*NoClassDefFoundError*

Comment: The sym-links have already been ruled out. Something in the bash script works in the root environment but not in yours. I suspect that either the `$SCALA_HOME` calculations and/or the `$TOOL_CLASSPATH` calculations are coming up with different results for the different environments, but there's no way to know until the script has been fully traced.

Comment: By fully tracing the script you mean??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153112/discussion-between-jwvh-and-shankhadeep-ghoshal).